# Conflict in routing between Laravel Nova and Dingo API

Tags: php, json, laravel, dingo-api, laravel-nova

I have a Laravel API server which only has one web route (test page), everything else is controlled via `dingo/api` package and all is working correctly.

In `config/api.php` I've set `'prefix' => env('API_PREFIX', '/')` as it's only an API server.

I've since installed Laravel Nova and kept getting JSON errors message on the `/nova` route: `No hint path defined for [nova]`.

I eventually figured out I need to change the prefix to `'prefix' => env('API_PREFIX', '/api')`. Now Nova works correctly, but my API routes are broken.

In Postman when I do GET `/test` (prefix `/`) works, but Nova doesn't, and when I do `/api/test/` (prefix `/api`), Nova does work but I get an error on the API return:

```
{
    "message": "",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException",
    "file": "/home/vagrant/Code/guest-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php",
    "line": 179,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "/home/vagrant/Code/guest-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 633,
            "function": "match",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\RouteCollection",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/vagrant/Code/guest-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 622,
            "function": "findRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Without an error message, I can't see what is wrong? Also, when I do `php artisan api:routes` I get the correct route back:

```
+------+----------+-----------------+------+-----------------------------------------------+-----------+------------+----------+------------+
| Host | Method   | URI             | Name | Action                                        | Protected | Version(s) | Scope(s) | Rate Limit |
+------+----------+-----------------+------+-----------------------------------------------+-----------+------------+----------+------------+
|      | GET|HEAD | /something/test |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@test | No        | v1         |          |            |
+------+----------+-----------------+------+-----------------------------------------------+-----------+------------+----------+------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding the `/api` as a fallback parameter, you should add the prefix to your `.env` file like: `API_PREFIX=api` as described [here](https://github.com/dingo/api/wiki/Configuration#version)